# Real-life applications of repeated games theory

Tags: game-theory, repeated-games

What are some scenarios in which the theory of repeated games have been applied?

I am looking, for example, for scenarios in which a government, a firm or a person accepted a decision which relied upon a result such as the [Folk theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_theorem_%28game_theory%29#cite_note-fisher-2).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has an influence in anti-trust cases involving tacit collusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe insights from repeated game theory have been used in designing the assignment scheme for security patrols in many occasions.

In this matter, the main research projects with close connections to applications that I know of are

(a) [PROTECT for the US Coast Guard](http://teamcore.usc.edu/projects/coastguard/)

(b) [TRUSTS for the Los Angeles Sheriff's Department](http://teamcore.usc.edu/projects/TRUSTS/)

(c) [IRIS for the Federal Air Marshal's Service](http://teamcore.usc.edu/projects/fam/)

(d) [LAX for the Los Angeles Airport Police](http://teamcore.usc.edu/ARMOR-LAX/)

(e) [GUARDS for the Transportation Security Administration](http://teamcore.usc.edu/GUARDS/)

which all revolve around the [teamcore research group at the University of Southern California](http://teamcore.usc.edu/projects/security/).

Examples of papers involving members of the group and repeated games (usually repeated Stackelberg security games) include:

- [Defender Strategies In Domains Involving Frequent Adversary Interaction](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2773374)
- [Learning Bounded Rationality Models of the Adversary in
  Repeated Stackelberg Security Games](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/boan/papers/ALA15_Debarun.pdf)
- [Conducting Longitudinal Experiments with Behavioral
  Models in Repeated Stackelberg Security Games on
  Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://teamcore.usc.edu/papers/2015/AAMAS15-HAIDM-CRC-DebarunKar.pdf)
- [A Game of Thrones": When Human Behavior Models Compete in Repeated Stackelberg Security Games](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2773329)